# Outlook Macro that saves a categorized email to a shared folder on Windows Explorer

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2016

Is there an Outlook macro that saves a copy of an email to a specific folder by category after its marked is read? For example, I check an email and categorize it by month; the email is left unread because i've toggled the option to manually leave emails read/unread. After I mark the email as read, a copy gets saved to a specific folder by category.

For example, If I categorize an email by March and it gets marked as read, it goes to the March folder. If i categorize by April, it goes to the April Folder after it's marked as read.

I'm using Exchange 365.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I found a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039209/outlook-vba-macro-for-saving-emails-copies-in-a-local-folder) that mentioned a macro to save your message locally.However, for category and reading status requirements, other codes may need to be added.

As a supplement, if you just would like to back up your messages with category locally, maybe we could try to work with [auto-archive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-older-items-automatically-25f44f07-9b80-4107-841c-41dc38296667) in Outlook, we could set the location and time period to archive your message into a .pst file automatically, so that you could directly open mutiple messages in a .pst file instead of a single .msg file.

Comment: Are you still researching for it? If my post is helpful to you, would you mind mark it to answer?